# How to plot a long path with Virtual Earth

Tags: javascript, virtual-earth

The obvious way to plot a path with virtual earth (VEMap.GetDirections) is limited to 25 points. When trying to plot a vehicle's journey this is extremely limiting.

How can I plot a by-road journey of more than 25 points on a virtual earth map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.lightmaker-manchester.com/blog/post.aspx?id=f081ca81-88a1-4958-9e15-b935d52e99cd) you need to call VEMap.GetDirections every 25 points until you reach the end of the route and then plot a custom shape of the complete route.